# How to compare two tables and identify a specific type of row to be returned?

Tags: python, sql, software-design

I have two tables with relatively different data.

the `photos` table is a table with all the relevant meta data for photos such as user_id, photo_id, datetime, name, etc.

I have another table `ratings` that holds liked/disliked data for each respective photo. The columns in this table would have rater_id(for the person rating the picture), photo_id, and the rating (like/dislike).

The user would be presented a picture (at random) and then pick whether they liked it or not. Every time the image is loaded/presented it would have to be something that they have not yet rated.

What I'm trying to do is return a `photo_id` where the user has not yet rated it.

I've thought of using join or union, but I'm having difficulty understanding how to best use those (or any other solution) for this application. Where my confusion lies is how I can compare the `ratings` table against the `photos` table, to only return the photos that have not been rated by `rater_id`.

---

Sample data

`photos table`

```
id | photo_id
-------------------------
1  | photo_123
2  | photo_456
3  | photo_432
4  | photo_642
-------------------------
```

`ratings table`

```
id | photo_id | rater_id | rating
---------------------------------
1 | photo_123 | user2 | 1
2 | photo_456 | user2 | 1
3 | photo_123 | user1 | 1
4 | photo_642 | user2 | 1
--------------------------------
```

Sample Result: return `photo_432` for `user2` because it has not yet had a rating in `ratings table`

Comment: Updated, hope that makes more sense now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical way would be `not exists`:

```
select p.*
from photos p
where not exists (select 1
                  from ratings r
                  where r.photo_id = p.id and
                        r.rater_id = @rater
                 )
order by rand()
limit 1;
```

There are more efficient ways to get a random row back if the table is big.

Comment: the table is expected to grow into the 10s of thousands (maybe more), what would the more efficient way be? I suppose just returning something that hasn't been rated is just fine as well - doesn't necessarily need to be random

Comment: @maestro416 . . . I said there are more efficient ways, not that they are simple.  To get things started, you might return an arbitrary photo and later decide if you really need a random photo.